# Does ssh has client side log file?

Tags: linux, windows-10, ssh, openssh

I want to know the history of SSH connections on client side (when and which remote host this machine connected to). I know `sshd` has logs on server side, is there similar thing on the client side?

I only need the connection history of myself and I'm using OpenSSH 7.6 on Windows10 and CentOS8. The thing is I forget about which remote host I used to ssh into; and I've mistakenly cleared my shell command history, so I can't just fetch it via `history` command.

Comment: The answer clearly depends on the client software. Also: are you the invoking user? or are you an admin trying to audit users? E.g. in Linux the client from OpenSSH does not log by default; you can tell it to, but the invoking user may override the config at runtime. The user's shell history is not the log you're after, as it's under the user's control. There is `auditd`, there's the firewall. Please [edit] the question and clarify: whose history do you want to know? as who? If you want to know your own history then: what is your SSH client software? your shell? your OS exactly?

Comment: Do you want to do this retroactively? Or are you prone to accept an answer that requires some setup in order to allow you to log *future* SSH connections?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski the original idea is to fetch the connection history since I forget about which remote host I used to ssh into. And I've mistakenly cleared my shell command history, so I cant just fetch it via `history` command

Comment: Check `known_hosts`, it may still be in the non-hashed format.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks! It's hashed, but I know the ssh port and the target remote IP is in the range of `192.168.*.*`, so I can run a brute-force search to find the right IP address according to [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31549/is-it-possible-to-find-out-the-hosts-in-the-known-hosts-file)! It really saves my day